Code Signing using Electron Forge for Windows
I want to code sign my electron application using sectigo EV USB which is using electron forge to package the app and wix-msi maker.
After referring to wix-msi config options I was able to make use of signWithParams options to sign the created msi but since the packager itself is not signing the exe(s) & dll(s), the wix maker just makes those into a msi installer.
Post installation of the msi the app remains unsigned since forge is not signing the app, How can I solve this problem?
I have tried the following:

Using postpackage hook to sign, but it is not a reliable solution
since i'll have to mention paths for code signing, and regardless the electron-windows-sign did not work because i was not able to import it since it is ES Module and i need to require a module in my forge.config.js. I can't use electron osx or notarize as it is for MacOS.



const sign = require('electron-windows-sign');

const appPath = 'sample/Path'; 
const certificateSubjectName = 'certificateSubjectName';

// Sign all .exe and .dll files in the packaged app
await sign({
  appPath,
  certificateSubjectName, /
});




Adding signing config to packagerConfig but i suppose it doesn't have that option in forge config:



win: {
          // The subject name of the certificate
          certificateSubjectName: 'Name of certificate',
          signWithParams: '/v /td sha256 /fd sha256 /n "Name of certificate"',
        },



P.S. I do not wish to use electron-builder.

I ended up using a post package hook since forge doesn't inherently has a signing config/option/feature.
In my forge.config.js:
const { execSync } = require('child_process');
const config = {
    // other configs
    packagerConfig : { 
        // packager Configs
    ),
    makers: [
        {
            "name": "@electron-forge/maker-wix",
            "config": {
              "ui": {
                "chooseDirectory": true,
              },
              appUserModelId: 'com.company.app',
              language: 1033, // English (US)
              signWithParams: '/tr http://timestamp.digicert.com /td sha256 /fd sha256 /a', // EV Signing Parameters
            }
        },
    ],
    hooks: {
      postPackage: async (forgeConfig, options) => {

        // signing files post package
        const appPath = path.join(options.outputPaths[0]); // you may use your relevatant options path
        console.log("appPath:", appPath);


        // Set up the executables or DLLs to be signed
        const executables = [
          path.join(appPath, 'app.exe'),
          path.join(appPath, 'd3dcompiler_47.dll'),
          path.join(appPath, 'ffmpeg.dll'),
          path.join(appPath, 'libEGL.dll'),
          path.join(appPath, 'libGLESv2.dll'),
          path.join(appPath, 'vk_swiftshader.dll'),
          path.join(appPath, 'vulkan-1.dll'),
          
        ];

        // Iterate over the files and sign them
        executables.forEach((file) => {
          console.log(`Signing file: ${file}`);

          // For Windows: Use signtool to sign the file
          execSync(`signtool sign /n "cert subject name" /tr http://timestamp.digicert.com /td sha256 /fd sha256 "${file}"`);
        });
      }
    }    
}

Note: you need to have signtool configured which is provided by windows SDK, enter "signtool" in cmd to check, if not present install signtool and set path to env variables.
